# Dynamics Business Central. How to create a task via API? How to add a note to a customer via API?

Tags: dynamics-365, dynamics-business-central

I'm using these API docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/api-reference/v2.0/ but there are no APIs for tasks/adding notes documented. It's still possible to do it via UI on the website so I'm assuming there is an API route for this. I'm using this base URL https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/production/api/v2.0/

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no standard API for this.

You would have to create your own extension for Business Central to expose an API with the desired feature.